# Where's the save file stored in Linux / Ubuntu?

Tags: steam, linux, the-great-ace-attorney-chronicles

The [PC Gaming Wiki](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Great_Ace_Attorney_Chronicles) says they're supposed to be in:

> <Steam-folder>/steamapps/compatdata/1158850/pfx/\userdata<user-id>\1158850\remote\

Which for me, seems to be:

> /home/[name]/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/compatdata/1158850/pfx/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Steam

But inside there, I can't find the `gear_##` files that [Steam Remote Storage](https://store.steampowered.com/account/remotestorageapp) is clearly picking up, and are there and operating, since I've saved 20+ saves and been able to reload.

Along with a search of my computer being unable to locate the files, but that might be just not letting the search run long enough. Or is it that I'm using Proton 7.[something] instead of the default Proton since the default breaks the videos?

Comment: There must be some tool which can help you find the savegame.  Maybe strace, ltrace, and/or lsof.  If you don't use the right options, though, strace or ltrace will give you too much and/or not enough output.

Comment: Why do you want to find your save file(s)?

Comment: @unforgettableidSupportsMonica - Backup and I wanna easily go back to scenes so I don't have to replay whole cases, etc.

Comment: If you are just looking to backup the save, the game supports Steam Cloud, so if you have it enabled it should already be backed up.  You can view and download these online [here](https://store.steampowered.com/account/remotestorage)

Comment: @Batophobia - Oh, right! Thanks for reminding me! ... Still wanna know where my local files are, though. And can't replace my saves if I don't know it anyway.

Comment: Steam's [online cloud save interface](https://store.steampowered.com/account/remotestorage) (same link as above) might help.  If you click the "Show Files" link for a game, it includes a relative path name.  For example, my Skyrim files show as under `my games/skyrim/saves`, which for Windows would indicate they are under /Documents instead of the steam folders.

Comment: @Batophobia - Yeah, but for my Ubuntu, it has a blank in that spot?

Comment: Did you read the info in the [Notes on PCGW](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Great_Ace_Attorney_Chronicles#Notes)? Don't have the game to test, but this seems relevant.

Comment: @l3l_aze - That's it! Yep. Do you wanna answer and get the rep? Or I can self-answer? "~/.steam/steam/userdata/<user-id>/1158850/remote/"

Comment: All good; I just pointed it out, you would've stumbled into it eventually :)

Comment: @l3l_aze - You say as if I were not just waiting for someone to tell me! If you hadn't said anything, it might've been another year or more until someone spoke up! Self-answering then, but thanking you lots!

Comment: Very welcome :) Just glad we were able to combine powers to solve it, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @l3l_aze for their comment:

> Did you read the info in the [Notes on PCGW](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Great_Ace_Attorney_Chronicles#Notes)? Don't have the game to test, but this seems relevant.

Following the link gives:

> Games with Steam Cloud support may store data in ~/.steam/steam/userdata//1158850/

Because that's it! My saves were at:

> ~/.steam/steam/userdata/1158850/remote/

Answer (score 0):

On my debian linux distro, where Steam is installed via [snap](https://snapcraft.io/), *some* Steam save-files are located at:

> ~/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/

Where `~` is /home/[user name]/

E.g:

```
~/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Beneath a Steel Sky/Saves
```

However, as @l3l-aze points out, many games write save-files to different locations.

E.i. I also have XCOM2 and Cities Skylines installed but neither seems to keep save-files in that directory.

```
.
├── Beneath a Steel Sky
│   ├── BASS.ini
│   ├── SKY
│   ├── Saves
│   └── ScummVM
├── Cities_Skylines
│   ├── Cities Skylines - Digital Artbook.pdf
│   ├── Cities Skylines - Soundtrack
│   ├── Cities.x64
│   ├── Cities_Data
│   ├── Files
│   ├── LauncherAssets
│   ├── Mono
│   ├── ThirdPartyLicenses.txt
│   ├── Tools
│   ├── dowser
│   ├── launcher-installer-linux
│   └── launcher-settings.json
└── XCOM 2
    ├── XCOM2.sh
    ├── XCOM2WotC
    ├── __MACOSX
    ├── bin
    ├── lib
    └── share
```

Comment: This is with Steam installed via Snap whereas OP seems to have used the default Steam installer. Also, that's usually just the folder for apps installed via Steam and not where most games actually store their save data.